# Configure Dynamic WCF-Ports in Biztalk

Tags: wcf, dynamic, binding, biztalk

I have a WCF port (which I got from add generated items>>Consume WCF service). I have exactly the same service on another server which I wanted to use. I reused all artifacts of previously consumed service and only made a copy of WCF port on Biztalk Administration side with different service address, then I bind both ports with appropriate virtual ports, and it is working fine. But is there any possibility to dynamically update binding information of WCF ports at run time with respect to input data (means I dont want to make multiple similar virtual ports in visual studio), I just want that if I want to add another service port I don't change my orchestration again and again. I only make physical port on Biztalk Administration Console side and bind it with some virtual port and it starts working....

Please let me know if there is some confusion...in question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use 'wcf custom' ports some of what the port does is configurable in the "soap action header". I'm not sure what you want to accomplish though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Role Links to dynamically send data to different servers. But binding file remains the same. There is no need to add additional binding files for each service and no need to amend BizTalk project again and again. Just configure ports and make additional parties and you are done.